# Consulta sql select entre 2 tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me piden es:
e. Mostrar las Plantas que recibieron mantenimientos que en su conjunto incluyen todos
los productos existentes

hice esto

```
select * from Planta p, Mantenimiento m
where p.Id_Planta = m.Planta_Id
and m.Mantenimiento_Id in(select nu.Mantenimiento_Id from Nutriente nu
                            where nu.Nutriente_Id = (
select distinct Nutriente_Id from Producto_Nutrientes
group by Nutriente_Id
having COUNT(Nutriente_Id) >= (select distinct COUNT(*) as Cantidad from Producto)));
```

pero esto devuelve las plantas que tienen 4 o mas mantenimientos

```
CREATE TABLE Nutriente (
    Mantenimiento_Id numeric(5),
    Nutriente_Id numeric(5),

    CONSTRAINT PK_NutrienteID PRIMARY KEY(Nutriente_Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MantenimientoID_Nutrientes FOREIGN KEY(Mantenimiento_Id) REFERENCES Mantenimiento(Mantenimiento_Id),
);

CREATE TABLE Producto (
    Producto_Id numeric(5),
    Descripcion varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PrecioPorGramo numeric(5,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ProductoID PRIMARY KEY(Producto_Id),
);

CREATE TABLE Producto_Nutrientes (
    Producto_Id numeric(5),
    Nutriente_Id numeric(5),
    gramos_usados numeric(5) NOT NULL,
    costo_usd numeric(5,2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_NutrienteID FOREIGN KEY (Nutriente_Id) REFERENCES Nutriente(Nutriente_Id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_ProductoID FOREIGN KEY (Producto_Id) REFERENCES Producto(Producto_Id),
);
```

Comment: Es una consulta compleja. Ayudaría mucho que compartas la estructura de las tablas y datos de prueba como código.

Comment: Listo! Cada planta es tiene un mantenimiento, el mantenimiento puede ser de tipo nutriente o (otro tipo que no importa) los mantenimiento de tipo nutriente tienen * producto_nutrientes que cada uno tiene un producto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, si mi logica no me engaña esto te debería de servir:

```
select * 
from planta p
inner join mantenimiento m on p.Id_Planta = m.Planta_Id 
inner join
(
    select mantenimiento_id 
    from Nutriente n 
    inner join Producto_Nutrientes pn on on n.nutriente_id=pn.nutriente_id
    group by mantenimiento_id
    having(count(distinct pn.producto_id)>=(select count(*) from Producto))
)a on a.mantenimiento_id=m.mantenimiento_id
```

Comment: Funciono! Graciasss